# Use POST function from Android, using Drupal as back end

Tags: android, rest, post, drupal, drupal-7

as the title said, 
I'm looking for a method to handle a POST request made from my Android front end to my Drupal back end.
I've already seen a lot of documentation and reference, like this one: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/build-mobile-app-sell-products-with-drupal

but I can't figure it out.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this [library](https://github.com/lemberg/d8androidsdk) for native Android applications to communicate with Drupal web servers?

Feature list:

- Synchronous and asynchronous requests
- Flexible object serialization / deserialization
- API can calculate object differences to perform patch requests
- Simple entities request

Comment: I got no problem with library, because on Android I've correctly implemented the POST request with Volley.
My real problem is that I don't know how to handle it on my Drupal website.
e.g. I want to check if the value passed with POST request is one rather than another one.

Answer (score 1):

### Use [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)

It sounds like you need to setup an API using something like a REST service. Drupal has a great module for this called [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services).

Essentially you can setup your Android app to use the POST method to push to your Drupal configured endpoint. 
EG: https://www.mysite.com/api/android/

Services is extremely flexible and you can have it work through basic CRUD operations for nodes or you can use hooks and use custom logic for a particular service you want to use and write custom PHP code to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you Steve,
I've already been using this module and I've created a module to read the POST data.
I can't understand, eventually, why with GET method I can read them, instead with POST method I cannot.

Comment: Try editing the existing service you've created and enable debugging mode. Also enable Drupal database logging and go to /admin/reports/dblog to see if anything jumps out. I'd recommend using something like DHC or Postman Chrome extensions to test the service out.

Comment: The service works if I call it via web;
e.g. : [link](http://example.com/endpoint/checkin/get?id=1&username=xyz).

No way to get it worked out from android code.